# Adjacency matrix from image skeleton and Corner list

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, adjacency-matrix

I have a project where I have to create a graph representation from image. First, I extracted the skeleton of the character using Zhang suen algorithm. Then, I extracted the interest points that will be used to represent the character by graph. My problem is from these points I want to create the adjacency matrix.
thanks for help.